# MySQL Database not showing in DataSource

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
I have installed MySQL Connector/NET 6.9.9(tried others),MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7

In Visual Studio,I have Added the reference MySqlData

But when i check the Datasource ,MySQL Database is Missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well anyways i tried Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition,It worked.

Comment: Try this link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd_vOhr7DXAhUJp5QKHWIlD58QFgg3MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkId%3D517284&usg=AOvVaw38M95R1I6q8ai-v5LHydWI

Comment: Thanks, but I finally came across my problem ;)